# Figuring out how to use hover function in jquery to highlight one cell only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table. I want to change the color of a cell, from black to red, when i move over that cell, I'm using the .hover method, and i'm having trouble figuring out how to make work accordingly to what i need.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.js"></script>
    <script>
    $board = $('#board')
    $(this).hover(function() {
        $('td').css('border-color', 'red');
    },
    function() {
        $('td').css('border-color', 'black')
    })
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    td {
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:black;
    }
    </style>        
    </head>
    <body>
    <table id="board">
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Shuffle" onclick="change()"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#board tr td").hover(function()
    {
        $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
    },
    function()
    {
        $(this).css('border-color', 'black')
    });
});

</script>
```

remember the type="text/javascript" on the script tag

when the page loads the $(document).ready function will be called, then it will set up the hover events.

when the mouse hovers over a td inside #board the first function will be called on `this`, the td you're hovering over.  when the mouse moves out it will call the second function putting the border back to black.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$board.find('td').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
},
function(){
    $(this).css('border-color', 'black')
})
```

Comment: I added it but it didn't seem to highlight anything now.